# Random tabs color in Productivity power tools

Tags: visual-studio-2013, productivity-power-tools

I use VS 2013, TFS and Productivity Power Tools. I set tabs color by project with "Color tabs by project" options in general settings in PPT. But when I merge all project source files by "Get Latest Version" TFS options, it change color at all open tabs. If Project 1 has defined blue color of tabs, after merging it has different color. Do you know why? It is possible to set persistent project tabs color?

Sorry for my english. If you have additional questions, don`t afraid to ask me. Thx

Comment: Where are you defining the color of tabs?

Comment: Tools->Options->Productivity Power Tools->Custom Document Well->Color Coding.